# Pull Table Information from code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 with 3 columns:

```
RDDID, SPDESC, SQLTEXT
```

Column `SQLTEXT` contains inline queries.

Is it possible to extract all table names from `SQLTEXT` and put them into a separate column?

INPUT:

```
RDDID|SPDESC|SQLTEXT
10XH1|DAGASC|SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1 AS A JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID=B.ID JOIN TABLE3 AS C ON A.ID=C.ID
```

OUTPUT

```
RDDID|SPDESC|COLX1|COLX2|COLX3|
10XH1|DAGASC|TABLE1|TABLE2|TABLE3
```

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Do you want a script that creates new columns on your existing table based on the table names in "SQLTEXT"?

Comment: @eclecticist: Yes: if it is possible, i tried but not able to get it as there are multiple from clause and even subquery associated with it. Please help

Comment: Are the queries stored in SQLTEXT able to be run successfully against your database, or are they queries for a different database?

Comment: @eclecticist: They are from same database

Comment: this is a very unconventional design. Where did COLX2 and COLX3 comes from ? I don't see that in the query

Comment: @Squirrel: it is column which has to be created to hold all table name.

Comment: @Squirrel Agreed - wouldn't the table columns be RDDID, SPDESC, SQLTEXT, TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE, ..., ...? It seems that SQLTEXT is deleted in the OUTPUT in the original post, which I don't think is intended.

Comment: Is it not possible in SQL, do i need to try with C#? kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

If you could TRY [Regex](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) or any simple technique to split the line with delimiter[space], 
You could try the following:

```
declare @query varchar(1000) = 'SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1 AS A JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID=B.ID JOIN TABLE3 AS C ON A.ID=C.ID'
 select b.name, 'ColX'+ cast(row_number() over( order by (select 0)) as varchar) as rn into #temp
 from dbo.RegExSplit(' ',@query,1) a join sys.tables b on a.match = b.name

 declare @cols varchar(100)
 select @cols = 
 stuff((select ',' +rn  from #temp for xml path('')),1,1,'')

 exec('select * from #temp pivot(max(name) for rn in ('+@cols+' ))piv')
 drop table #temp
```